# Shortcode for sectors

Tags: shortcode

We've been given a WordPress site that has the following shortcode in the body of the page.

```
[show_case_studies post_type="case-study" posts_per_page="15" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order" include_excerpt="true" image_size="full"]`
```

We've been asked to break the content down further so that only content of a certain sector is shown. We tried this ourselves by using the following.

```
[show_case_studies post_type="case-study" sector="secondary-school" posts_per_page="15" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order" include_excerpt="true" image_size="full"]`
```

That didn't work.

Comment: There is no way anyone can help with that as that shortcode is custom to a plugin or a theme and not familiar to all.  Without knowing what this shortcode is suppose to do and how the code looks, its anyone's guess I am afraid.

Comment: You will need to find and post the PHP that processes the shortcode. Look for `add_shortcode('show_case_studies',` in the theme, plugin, or mu-plugin files on the site.